# Correct way to render an custom entity and its custom field?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

In my module, I have a custom entity `LocationEntity` and it uses a custom field type `CoordinateItem` which has 2 sub fields `X`, `Y`.

So what is the correct way of Drupal 8 to:

1) Render this `LocationEntity` in a twig template?

- What I'm doing is just send the entity to twig template `'#loc1'` and manually render its each field value using getter method `{{ loc1.getName() }}`. It works but I'm sure this is not the correct way to do.

2) If question 1 has another correct way then how to have more than one templates for rendering the entity?

- For example, one simple layout with less fields and one detail layout with all fields.

3) In the entity, I defined to use the custom field `CoordinateItem`. But now what to do with its getter and setter, because it's not a single sub field inside?

- Getter if `$this->get('coord')` -> a `FieldItemList` object.
- Getter if `$this->get('coord')->value` -> `null`.
- Setter? What type is the parameter?

4) I wrote a formatter for `CoordinateItem` to show its sub fields. But again I don't know how to use this formatter to render this custom field in the main (entity) template?

- Maybe this is related to question 1 and 2?

Answer (score 3):

#### View Builder

- 1. Set the `view_builder` in ContentEntityType annotation to EntityViewBuilder to inherit some default behavior (or write your own).
- 2. Set your `canonical` router to something like what [`content_entity_example`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/content_entity_example!content_entity_example.module/group/content_entity_example/8) does in the examples module.

     - Berdir suggests using [DefaultHtmlRouteProvider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Routing!DefaultHtmlRouteProvider.php/class/DefaultHtmlRouteProvider/8) though that class is marked as `@internal` so it may not be stable to use long term.

content_entity_example.routing.yml

```
entity.content_entity_example_contact.canonical:
  path: '/content_entity_example_contact/{content_entity_example_contact}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'content_entity_example_contact'
    _title: 'Contact Content'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'content_entity_example_contact.view'
```

- 3. Change your entity theme to something like what [node module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/node_theme/8) does, and have it display as a render element.
- 4. Use your entity or bundle's field display page to change what field formatters a given field will use.
- 5. Then you can print out `{{ elements }}` in the template for it to go through the entire render array for a given view mode. Again, you can follow something similar to [node module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8).

Comment: Instead of 2. use the DefaultHtmlRouteProvider, that generates standard routes automatically based on the link templates.

Comment: Not sure why it is @internal, it's IMHO definitely the recommended way to do this these days. I think It's just internal because we keep adding more features to it in minor releases, but we recently agreed that we can do that to all interfaces/classes.